# log file: only process entries older than "MMM DD HH:MM:SS"

Tags: text-processing, logs, date

I need to process my logfile `/var/log/mylogs.log`. I am only interested in the new entries, lets say, since `Jul 20 15:00:00` but the log contains older entries as well.

Is there any simple way, how I could `cat` only entries older than certain date?

Comment: Which thing do you want? Your question says your only interested in new entries since date X, but then you're also asking how to `cat` entries older than a date X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a little `bash` script that uses `date` to parse the dates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Your date threshold
limit="Jul 20 15:00:00"
## Your limit in seconds since the UNIX epoch
limit_seconds=$(date -d "$limit" +%s)

while read line; do
    ## Extract the date and convert to seconds since epoch for comparison
    date=$(date -d "$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f -4)" +%s);
    ## Is this newer than the limit? If yes, print the line
    if [ "$date" -ge "$limit_seconds" ]; then
    echo "$line"
    fi

done
```

Save this script in your path (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/parse_log.sh`) and you can then run it like this:

```
parse_log.sh < /var/log/mylogs.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to do this with perl:

```
perl -wlne '/^Jul\ 20\ 15\:00\:00/ .. eof() and print' /path/to/logfile.txt
```

You might want to adjust the regex to your exact needs.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that the exact string "Jul 20 15:00:00" will most likely not be in the logs. The log might look like this: `"Jul 20 14:55:12"`
`"Jul 20 15:02:10"`

Comment: Also, what's the point of `.. eof()`? You could just say `perl -ne '/^Jul\ 20\ 15\:00\:00/ and print'`

Comment: @terdon Just easy to replace with the date where you want to end... But indeed, it's pointless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is best done in a language which makes date manipulations easy. I assume that each log line begins with a date in `mmm dd HH:MM:SS` format and that all log entries are from the current year.

```
<var/log/mylogs.log perl -MDate::Parse -e '
    $cutoff = str2time($ARGV[0]);
    while (<STDIN>) {
        print if /^(... [ 0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])/ and
                 str2time($1) <= $cutoff
    }
' 'Jul 20 15:00:00'
```

This snippet prints all lines with older dates. If you want the newer entries, reverse the comparison (`str2time($1) >= $cutoff`). When printing older entries, you can save a bit of processing by bailing out as soon as a too-late entry is reached.

```
<var/log/mylogs.log perl -MDate::Parse -e '
    $cutoff = str2time($ARGV[0]);
    while (<STDIN>) {
        exit if /^(... [ 0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])/ and
             str2time($1) > $cutoff;
        print;
    }
' 'Jul 20 15:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for same answer I found this old topic

And I solved it by using grep with `-B` option:

`cat /var/log/mylogs.log | grep -B 1000 "Jul 20 15:00:00"`

It will show line with that date and 1000 lines before it. Simple and easy. You just need to be sure that you are `grep`ing date that exist in your log file. 
Same way with `-A` option you can search for newer entries.

Answer (score -1):

Try sed aswell:

```
sed -n '/^Jul\ 20\ 15\:00\:00/,/eof()/p' /path/to/logfile.txt
```