# Only show entries of the last hour of log file

Tags: logs, filter

I have a huge logfile access.log with entries like:

```
192.11.111.111 - - [05/Mar/2021:00:00:02 +0100] "GET ..."
192.250.14.80 - - [05/Mar/2021:00:00:09 +0100] "GET ..."
12.249.66.42 - - [05/Mar/2021:00:00:13 +0100] "GET ..."
```

How can I get/filter entries of the last hour only?

Comment: Do you want a program that will work out automatically what the "last hour" is, or do you just want a pattern you can use from the command line, such as `grep '04/Mar/2021:23:` ?

Comment: I guess it is sorted by time?

Comment: If your system runs linux with systemd and your service logs through journald you can use: `journalctl --since "1 hour ago"` (and filter even further with the service name).

Comment: @StephenHarris I just need a pattern to get all lines with entries of the last hour. In the next step I plan to sort by the count of access per IP, to determine which IPs where accessing the Server how often.

Comment: @kaliko It's a linux server but managed by my hoster. I have ssh access, but only limited rights. All logs are stored in access.log. I can not use the journalctl command

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

age() { python -c '
import sys
from datetime import datetime
print(int((datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])).seconds))
' "$@"
}

tac access.log | while IFS= read line; do
    date=$(cut -d' ' -f4 <<< "$line")
    age=$(age "$date" "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
    [ $age -gt 3600 ] && break
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

**Explanation:**

- Create a function to get the age of a date string, I use `python` `datetime` module for it.
- Then loop the lines of the file in reverse with `tac log | while ...`
- Get the date string with `cut`.

  - you need to remove `-d' '` if your delimiter is tab instead of space
  - or use `awk '{print $4}' <<< "$line"` instead
  - or use `read ip some thing date tz else <<< "$line"`).
- Get the age with the function we defined in the first step
- When seconds > 3600 (=1hour), stop the loop (`break`)
- Otherwise, print the line (or do whatever)

**Some additional notes:**

- As I ignore the timezone (+0100), this assumes we are in the same timezone as the log file. If you have log files from other time zones, you may need to improve the `age` function. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530069/how-do-i-get-a-value-of-datetime-today-in-python-that-is-timezone-aware) and read the date as `cut -d' ' -f4,5`.
- You could obviously do the whole thing with `python`, however, reading a file in reverse without having to read the whole file [seems not that easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23646049/7365127) and I simply like `tac`.
- You could use `date` and `bc` or so to calculate the age ([like it's done here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85698/236063)), but as your date format is not supported out of the box, this would be a pain. Imo, `datetime.strptime` is perfect for that.
- The good thing about the `age` function: it is very reusable for any kind of task. Just call it the same `strptime` can read it and is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

  ```
  age "date_string" "format"
  ```